# Ocaml Syntax Error

Tags: syntax, ocaml, lazylist

I'm using an implementation of lazy lists where the type can be either `Nil` or `Cons (value, thunk)`, where `thunk` is a function from unit to the rest of the list.

I'm trying to write a function `cross`, which would function as `List.combine` does. Unfortunately, I'm having syntax errors.

```
open Sequence;;
    let rec (cross : 'a Sequence.t -> 'b Sequence.t -> ('a * 'b) Sequence.t) = match seq1 with
        Nil -> match seq2 with
            Cons (value2, thunk2) -> Cons ((Nil, value2), function () -> (cross Nil (thunk2 ())))
      | Cons (value1, thunk1) -> match seq2 with
            Nil -> Cons ((value1, Nil), function() -> (cross Nil (thunk1 ())))
          | Cons (value2, thunk2) -> Cons ((value1, value2), function() -> (cross (thunk1 ()) (thunk2 ())))
```

This produces the error:

```
Error: Unbound value seq1
```

what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

This type checks, but is not of the type I'm looking for.

```
let rec cross (seq1 : 'a Sequence.t) (seq2 : 'b Sequence.t) : ('a * 'b) Sequence.t = match seq1 with
    Nil -> match seq2 with
        Cons (value2, thunk2) -> Cons ((Nil, value2), function () -> (cross Nil (thunk2 ())))
  | Cons (value1, thunk1) -> match seq2 with
        Nil -> Cons ((value1, Nil), function() -> (cross Nil (thunk1 ())))
      | Cons (value2, thunk2) -> Cons ((value1, value2), function() -> (cross (thunk1 ()) (thunk2 ())))

val cross :
  'a Sequence.t Sequence.t ->
  'a Sequence.t Sequence.t -> ('a Sequence.t * 'a Sequence.t) Sequence.t =
  <fun>
```

This is not the type of cross that I want. I'm looking for:

```
'a Sequence.t -> 'b Sequence.t -> ('a * 'b) Sequence.t
```

Comment: What is the type error you are getting? Shouldn't you be matching with Sequence.Nil and Sequence.Cons?

Comment: I used "open Sequence;;" further up the file. edited to include that.

Comment: What's cross is trying to do ? (i think i've been confused by "functions as List.combine", you're trying to merge 2 sequences? )

Comment: You should post the code for thunk1 too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are going to kick yourself... where is seq1 defined?

```
let rec (cross : 'a Sequence.t -> 'b Sequence.t -> ('a * 'b) Sequence.t) =
```

You define the type of cross, but you don't bind the variables to anything (I guess, you can say that).

```
let rec cross (seq1:'a Sequence.t) (seq2:'a Sequence.t) :('a * 'b) Sequence.t =
```

*EDIT:*

I think your matching is well, mis-matched. Use `begin ... end` blocks around the cases, I think what is happening (and since I don't have Sequence, I cannot verify) is that the match cases you intend for the outer match are being applied to the inner one, matching seq2. for example,

```
match x with
| 0 -> match y with
    | 1 -> "x:0, y:1"
| 2 -> match y with
    | 0 -> "y:0, x:2"
```

Although, spatially, it looks fine, the second match, `match y with` is bound with the `| 2 -> ...` match case. Here is a version with the `being ... end` keywords surrounding the match cases. The second begin ... end isn't needed, but it's probably a good idea to do it anyway for clarity.

```
match x with 
| 0 -> begin match y with
    | 1 -> "x:0, y:1" end
| 2 -> begin match y with
    | 0 -> "y:0, x:2" end
```

Comment: +1: I got +1 while my answer was more recent (by a couple of seconds but still...).

Answer (score 2):

in the first line, you're trying to match against seq1, but this value is unbound meaning that it's nowhere to be found.

That's exactly the same as :

```
# let t =
  match t1 with
  _ -> ();;
Error: Unbound value t1
```

You have to name your arguments.

Answer (score 2):

For your updated question, the reason the types are `'a Sequence.t Sequence.t` is because of the line

```
Cons ((Nil, value2), ...)
```

Recall that `Nil` is a sequence itself, so by putting that there it forces all the elements of the input sequences to be sequences too.

Comment: ok, so then how do I express ('a * 'b) without making both elements sequences?

Comment: @Rosarch: Well, I dunno; because there is no obvious way to express an "empty" value. Let me ask you this: suppose you wanted to write this function for regular lists, i.e. you wanted to make a function that is " 'a list -> 'b list -> ('a * 'b) list ". How would you do it? How would you handle lists of different lengths?

Comment: @newacct +1 : List.combine does not handle lists of different lengths, you've got an InvalidArgument. I don't really know what you can do since there's no empty value. That's a good point. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you have mentioned a name which has not been defined (technically “bound to a
value”). This might happen if you have mistyped the name.